# how to get text from clipboard in python and paste in utf-8?

Tags: python

I have some utf-8 text in the clipboard and a utf-8 .txt file with nothing in it.

If I open the file in notepad++, and paste using ctrl+v, I get it in utf-8 format, without those ?'s in it.

But if I use a python code to get text from clipboard and open the file in append mode and write it there, then look at the file in notepad++, i see the ?'s in it.

Is there some special python code that can get text from the clipboard and write it to an empty utf-8 file, such that if I were to look at the file after in notepad++, i wouldn't see those ?'s.

Anyone know?

Comment: Can you post your python code for getting the text from the clipboard and writing to the file?

Comment: Unicode != utf-8. When you paste into Notepad++ it's pasting Unicode, then when you save the file it is optionally converted to utf-8. You want the same to happen in Python, when you take a string from the clipboard you want to take it as a Unicode string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `codecs` module:

```
 import codecs

 file = "/path/to/save/file.txt" 

 # instead of open(file,'w') do:
 f = codecs.open(file, encoding='utf-8',mode='w+')

 # Write a unicode string to the file.
 f.write(u'\u4500 blah blah blah\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This makes my Selenium script so much shorter!!!! :)